# Java 8 optional list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to achieve following:
Given an list of  object. Return starting 5 object which fulfill a criteria.

I am able to first element:

```
optionServiceObject.map((p) -> (List<ServiceAttribute>) p.getFoor())
                   .flatMap((v2) -> v2.stream().filter((v3) -> v3.hasBar())
                   .map(v3 -> v3.getBar())
                   .findFirst()
```

But unable to get, how to get starting 5 element matching the criteria into list.

Comment: "Return starting 5 object which fulfill a criteria." which criteria ? your code is unclear...

Comment: Criteria is already covered in code. Object having hasBar() as true.

Comment: Instead of `.findFirst()` try `.limit(5)`

Comment: That gives "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream<Bar> to Optional<Object>"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get object number 5, skip the first four objects with `skip(4)`:

```
Optional<Bar> fifthObject = optionServiceObject
                    .map((p) -> (List<ServiceAttribute>) p.getFoor())
                    .flatMap((v2) -> v2.stream().filter((v3) -> v3.hasBar())
                    .map(v3 -> v3.getBar())
                    .skip(4)
                    .findFirst();
```

The result will be empty if you have less than 5 matching objects.

If you want to get at most 5 matching objects, use `limit(5)` and collect the results to the `List`:

```
List<Bar> fiveObjects = optionServiceObject
                    .map((p) -> (List<ServiceAttribute>) p.getFoor())
                    .flatMap((v2) -> v2.stream().filter((v3) -> v3.hasBar())
                    .map(v3 -> v3.getBar())
                    .limit(5)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I want to achieve 2nd use case. But it gives  "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Object> to 
  List<String>"

Comment: Try sticking .map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty).collect(Collectors.toList()); to the end to get back to a lsit